# Fibers of $V(ax_0^2+bx_1x_2)$ in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

What are the fibers of $Z=V(ax_0^2+bx_1x_2)$ for $(a:b)\in \mathbb{P}^1, (x_0:x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{P}^2$?

If we fix $(a:b)$ or $(x_0:x_1,x_2)$ and dehomogenize, we can see that $Z$ is a family of curves or lines respectively. Do these describe the fibers of $Z$?

Comment: To be a little bit picky, I claim that you should only talk about the fibres of a _map_. So you can talk about the fibres of the projection $Z \rightarrow \mathbf{P}^1$ or the projection $Z \rightarrow \mathbf{P}^2$, but not simply "the fibres of $Z$."

Comment: Anyway, your description of the fibres of $Z \rightarrow \mathbf{P}^1$ is right: they are plane conics. However, the fibres of $Z \rightarrow \mathbf{P}^2$ are not lines --- if we fix $(x_0:x_1:x_2)$, we get a unique solution for $(a:b)$, so the fibre is a single point. (No need to dehomogenise, by the way!)